# Flyout Control for Header menu Windows 8 using XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-8, flyout

I am have created a Flyout Control (extending UserControl) in order to have Header Menu navigation for a Windows 8 App using C# and XAML.

In this layout I have some buttons with Click listeners. These buttons are used for the navigation among the various pages of the app.

Thus, I would like to ask you how can I access the parent page's Frame in order to navigate to the other pages?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get the frame with

```
var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
```

Comment: I had tried this, but an ArgumentNullException is thrown. Addition info: Value cannot be null. This exception is thrown in the OnNavigatedFrom method of the LayoutAwarePage.cs. Any hint about this?

Comment: I was thinking you needed to get ahold of the frame from within the user control. Why do you need to acquire the current frame from a page you are leaving?  OnNavigatedFrom is invoked immediately after the Page is unloaded and is no longer the current source of a parent Frame, thus the reason you are getting a ArgumentNullException being thrown.

Comment: So, since I want to navigate to another page when I click on a button of the Flyout Control, which is the correct way to do this?

Comment: In the button handler, acquire the frame using the code above then use frame.navigate to your new page